# Security group in ec2 linux instance need to be edited every time

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, groups

I have created linux instance and installed wordpress on it. Every time I open my page after making change in code via commandline login , it shows this message -

```
The connection has timed out  
               The server at ec2-x-x-114-133.compute-1.amazonaws.com is taking too long to respond.
```

Currently my security group looks like this -

[image]

Where source is displayed as `Custome IP`

When I edit the security group as below, by selecting `MY IP` in place of Custom IP, it start functioning. Why does it change automatically ?

[image]

How do I set security group setting permanently, Please bear, I am pretty new with ec2 instance.

Answer (score 1):

The behavior you are describing is probably because you are connecting from different networks and/or your network does not have a static public IP. Basically, your IP has changed and you therefor need to edit the security group with your new IP.

I would suggest some reading about AWS EC2 security groups and dynamic vs. static IPs.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-network-security.html
http://whatismyipaddress.com/dynamic-static